# Clase condicional en VUE

Tags: vue.js

quiero crear un clase dinámica en `vue js` pero nio me sale

me arroja un error de que `item` no esta definodo, pero no se porqué

ya que el `item` esta definido en el `v-for`

en el

```
<i v-bind:class="deleting && item.id == task.id ? 'fas fa-sync fa-spin':'fas fa-times'"></i>
```

```
<tr v-for="item in tasks" v-bind:key="item.id" >
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.description}}</td>
   <td>{{item.createdAt}} Creacion</td>
   <td>{{item.status}}</td>
   <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="edit(item)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="remove(item)"><i v-bind:class="deleting && item.id == task.id ? 'fas fa-sync fa-spin':'fas fa-times'"></i></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ¿De dónde viene la variable `ta`? ¿De `data`? ¿`computed`? ¿`setup`?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza es `item` , `ta` no es, y esta esta en el `foreach`

Comment: Ok. Pero sigo sin entender de dónde sale `ta`. Si no sabés de dónde viene, no debería sorprenderte que aparezca como que no está definido. Además, ¿el `v-bind:key` no tendría que ser `item.id`? ¿Por qué usar `ta` si ni siquiera sabemos de dónde viene o qué es lo que tiene?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente, no se pueden iterar etiquetas `<tr>` con un `v-for`.

Ya que si intentas hacerlo, justamente te aparecerá como si no existe la variable que quieres iterar.

En tu caso, es por eso que tienes el error de que `item` no está definido.

Así que la manera correcta de hacer esa iteración es utilizando la etiqueta `<template>` , como recomienda [esta respuesta que habla sobre eso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013026/15385861).

Debido a que desconozco en dónde defines exatamente la variable `task` y cómo la utilizas, intenté hacer una reconstrucción de tu código cambiándole eso y agregándole datos falsos para hacerlo funcional.

De esa manera, conseguí crearte el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vm',
  data: function () {
    return {
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Hola mundo",
          description: "Lorem impsum",
          createdAt: "1/2/22",
          status: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Hello world",
          description: "impsum Lorem",
          createdAt: "2/2/22",
          status: false
        }
      ],
      deleting: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vm">
<template v-for="item in tasks">
  <tr>
   <i v-bind:class="deleting && item.id == item.id ? 'fas fa-sync fa-spin':'fas fa-times'"></i>
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.description}}</td>
   <td>{{item.createdAt}} Creacion</td>
   <td>{{item.status}}</td>
   <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="edit(item)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="remove(item)"><i v-bind:class="deleting && item.id == item.id ? 'fas fa-sync fa-spin':'fas fa-times'"></i></button>
    </td>
   </tr>
</template>
</div>
```

Observa que si ejecutas este código, en ningún momento te saldrá el error de que `item` no está definido.

Por el contrario, dicha variable se está iterando correctamente.

Comment: task, es un estado, que lo modifico con al darle cick en el boton, pero eso si lo reconoce, el cual no lo reconoce es el `item`

Comment: SI pruebas el código, vas a ver que el problema con el `item` ya no existe. ¿Soluciona entonces esta respuesta tu problema? De no ser así, podrías decirnos cuál es el verdadero problema con tu código y agregarnos más datos de él. Como por ejemplo mostrarnos el código completo en donde defines el estado `task`.

Comment: return {
      tasks: [ ],
      deleting: true,
      task: {}
    }

`task` es un objeto unico, el error que me sale es que `item` no existe, no tengo idea de porqué

Comment: `<i v-bind:class="deleting && task.id == item.id ? 'fas fa-sync fa-spin':'fas fa-times'"></i>`, la idea es que salga un `loading` mientras se esta eliminado

Comment: En realidad me refería a que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código de `task` ahí, de esa forma le das un contexto a ese código. Tal y como está ahora, desconozco el lugar exacto en donde lo defines. Y por el otro lado, mi respuesta es justamente la explicación de porqué el item aparece como que no existe... como dije ahí, es porque no se puede iterar una etiqueta `<tr>` con un `v-for`. Insisto con mi pregunta: ¿qué necesita mi respuesta para que pueda resolver tu problema?